# Sending schema with nusoap in PHP to .NET webservice

Tags: php, xml, web-services, schema, nusoap

Not sure what my question is here but I need some pointers.

This is part of a guide for sending Insurance policy information to a webservice to get a quote in return. Where 'schema' and 'xml' need to be replaced.

```
<soap:Body>
    <Quote xmlns="http://[etc]/">
      <PolicyDetails>
        <xsd:schema>schema</xsd:schema>xml</PolicyDetails>
    </Quote>
</soap:Body>
```

I am using nusoap (PHP soap extensions aren't on the server and I can't install them) and I would normally send something like:

```
$client->call('Quote', 'PolicyDetails' => $xml);
```

But this doesn't work. I get the error:

```
Error: soap:Server: Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I assume because I'm missing out the 'schema' part. I know what the XML should look like but not what I have to add to 'schema' or how I should do it. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know what variables you need to send ?

Try my code which I use in my webserwice case:

```
<?php
require_once("nusoap/lib/nusoap.php");

/* Initialize parameter */
$param = array(
     'PolicyDetails' => array(
        'variableName' => 'variable',
        'variableName2' => 'variable2',
     ),
);

/* create client */
$endpoint = "https://webserviceurl";
$mynamespace = "";

$client = new nusoap_client($endpoint, true);
$err = $client->getError();
if ($err) {
    exit();
}

$response = $client->call('Quote', $param, $mynamespace);
$err = $client->getError();
if ($err) {
    exit();
}

print_r($response);

?>
```

Comment: Yes, this is pretty much what I have but I get the error. I don't know how I'm supposed to define 'schema' here or if nusoap does that automatically somehow.

Comment: Post here all variables what this `Quote` function receive, I think that you need only correctly create `$param` array to succeed

Comment: There are quite a few. And for reasons of confidentiality I don't think I should go into them here. I've requested an example of a valid response from the web service developer to see how it compares to what I've generated.

Comment: Show me what is your request using `echo $client->request;`. What about the `$xml`... you get it from file or you create it from some kind of array?